# Simple, well indexed, MySQL-query takes about a second

Tags: mysql, performance

I use the following query in my web-app. It is querying a results table that consists of prices from webshops at a given time. It has approx 1 million records. Indexes are one shopID, StartTime, pID and WebsiteID.

The query:

```
SELECT shopID, tresults.StartTime, tresults.Price
FROM tresults
WHERE tresults.pID = 7  
    AND WebsiteID = 1 AND StartTime BETWEEN "2013-4-10" AND "2013-4-11"
    AND tresults.shopID IN (44, 68, 23, 16, 144, 8, 9, 5) 
GROUP BY tresults.StartTime, tresults.Price 
ORDER BY tresults.StartTime, tresults.Price
```

The explain result:

```
1, SIMPLE, tresults, index_merge, PRIMARY,idxPID,idxWebsite,idxStartTimeASC,idxStartTimeDESC,fk_shopID, idxPID,idxWebsite, 4,4, , 1062, Using intersect(idxPID,idxWebsite); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Looks fine to me, but still the query takes about one second to complete. This is not acceptable in a fast website.

How can I speed things up?

note: the speed looks like it is dependant upon the number of shopID's

Thanks!

Comment: You did notice tresults.pID=7 is mentioned twice? How many rows are selected from those milion rows? Why are you grouping? Order by should be enough...

Comment: pID=7 shouldnt be there twice (it makes no difference in performance though). It is selecting approx 500 rows from those million. The grouping is in there because I think that's necessary for the chart that I'm creating out of the results. Removing it doesn't make the performance different unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idxTresults_pwsp ON tresults (pId, WebsiteID, StartTime, Price);
```

This is the best way to narrow down the search, and it also prevents the "Using temporary" and "Using filesort".

```
mysql> EXPLAIN 
SELECT shopID, tresults.StartTime, tresults.Price
FROM tresults
WHERE tresults.pID = 7  
    AND WebsiteID = 1 AND StartTime BETWEEN '2013-4-10' AND '2013-4-11'
    AND tresults.shopID IN (44, 68, 23, 16, 144, 8, 9, 5) 
GROUP BY tresults.StartTime, tresults.Price 
ORDER BY tresults.StartTime, tresults.Price 
\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tresults
         type: ref
possible_keys: idxpid,idxStarttime,fkShop_id,idxTresults_pwsp
          key: idxTresults_pwsp
      key_len: 9
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
```

The reason this works better is that the first two columns of the index help to pick just the right subset of rows for a specific pID and WebsiteID.  Since you picked a single specific pID and WebsiteID, then the chosen entries in this new index are already guaranteed to be sorted in the best order for the StartTime and Price, so the query doesn't need to create a temporary table.  It just accesses the entries in the order they're stored in the index.

PS:  MySQL doesn't support "ascending" versus "descending" indexes.  It accepts the keywords, but it doesn't do anything different with them.  So you don't need both types of index on a given column.

PPS:  Don't use double-quotes for string or date literals.  Use single-quotes, to comply with ANSI SQL.  You'll be better off getting into this habit if you ever use other RDBMS brands, because most other brands use quotes according to the standard.  MySQL allows double-quotes to be used in a non-standard way.

Comment: Wow... that is working like a charm. Thanks for: 1. speeding up my webapp's page load with about half a second, 2. making me understand the way multi-col indexes work and 3. getting rid of my double quote-bad-habit. I'm sorry for medina above. But this has to be the one and only right answer.

Answer (score 3):

your query is not really good as you think. It is using "Using temporary" and "Using filesort". Which means It's been saved in your file system to be manipulated by the parser and making the query much slower.

To try to improve it you can try to make the fields on the Clause WHERE match the Index you've got in your table. Or even, create a new index in the following order: pID, websiteID, startTime if your query is gonna run always with theses elements.

I also didn't understand why you have the field tresults.pID twice in your query.

[EDIT]

Hey mate, you are getting temporary tables because you are using aggregation functions to manipulate your result set, e.g. GROUP BY, ORDER BY, HAVING and so on. That is fine as long as the temporary tables is kept in memory, which is the faster way to access data. The problem is when those table reach such size that the parser has to bring them to the file system.

You can try to find the best balance change the values for tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size. Also, try to avoid using blog/text columns once the Memory storage does not support them.

More information you can find on the official documentation.

Comment: I created the index you suggested, but it is still using temporary and filesort. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmm... i just created one index on tresults.pID and tresults.WebsiteID. That made a significant improvement. Query-time went from 1 second to 0.15 second. Eventough the explain results still says that mysql uses temporary and filesort. I'm happy for now! ;)Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks Medina for the edit. But Bill Karwin's solution is even faster than yours